# Sideloading a current date into a php script

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm now helping a friend with a WordPress website. That's a website for a hotel, and they have three kinds of prices for different seasons. Besides the separate page with a price list, the prices are also displayed at every page describing rooms. There are lots of pages and I'm afraid that they will forget to update it manually every time the prices change. I've had a thought whether it's possible to create a PHP script which can sideload the current date and then, using the if construction, display the correct price.

Can anybody help me, how can I sideload the current date into a php file to do the comparison?

Answer (score -1):

You can use a PHP code widget like this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-code-widget/

Within this widget you can use your own code e.g.

```
<?php
//etc.
mysql_query("SELECT price.value from prices where price.date between DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW();//this will give you the price which price-date is within 24 hours from now
//etc

?>
```